# Fixed position - wrong width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I am beginner in JS and Bootstrap. I use in my project Bootstrap 4 and jQuery.

I have this code:

```
<body>
<section id="planner">
    <div class="nav">
        <a href="#" class="active">Konfiguracja planu</a>
        <a href="#">Posiłki</a>
        <a href="#">Raporty</a>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h2>About</h2>
                <p>

                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                    industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
                    and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the
                    leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s
                    with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
                    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h2 class="cow">qwerty</h2>
                <div class="tableBox">
                    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                    <div id="stick-here"></div>
                    <div id="stickThis">
                        <div id="accordion">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                                        <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne"
                                                aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                            Collapsible Group Item #1
                                        </button>
                                    </h5>
                                </div>

                                <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne"
                                     data-parent="#accordion">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry
                                        richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor
                                        brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor,
                                        sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda
                                        shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson
                                        cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo.
                                        Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt
                                        you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
                                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                                        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                                                data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false"
                                                aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                                            Collapsible Group Item #2
                                        </button>
                                    </h5>
                                </div>
                                <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo"
                                     data-parent="#accordion">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry
                                        richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor
                                        brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor,
                                        sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda
                                        shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson
                                        cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo.
                                        Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt
                                        you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
                                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                                        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                                                data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false"
                                                aria-controls="collapseThree">
                                            Collapsible Group Item #3
                                        </button>
                                    </h5>
                                </div>
                                <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree"
                                     data-parent="#accordion">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry
                                        richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor
                                        brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor,
                                        sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda
                                        shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson
                                        cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo.
                                        Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt
                                        you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-3qaqj0lc6sV/qpzrc1N5DC6i1VRn/HyX4qdPaiEFbn54VjQBEU341pvjz7Dv3n6P"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
    function sticktothetop() {
        var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
        var top = $('#stick-here').offset().top;
        if (window_top > top) {
            $('#stickThis').addClass('stick');
            $('#stick-here').height($('#stickThis').outerHeight());
        } else {
            $('#stickThis').removeClass('stick');
            $('#stick-here').height(0);
        }
    }

    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(sticktothetop);
        sticktothetop();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Prview: http://serwer1356363.home.pl/pub/_demo/

When I move the screen down - on the right, component accordion "sticks" to the top of the screen.
This is correct. The problem is that this accordion comes out of its columns (it gets too wide). How to fix it?

Comment: you are changing your webpage a lot create a codesandbox and i can control it from there, otherwise i can't test it

Comment: sorry. I refresh my code: http://serwer1356363.home.pl/pub/_demo/

Comment: https://jsbin.com/ upload your html and css right here, click ctrl +s and send me the link

Comment: https://jsbin.com/fobiyajunu/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use javascript to set width to `#stickThis` according to its parent width at the same time you add the sticky class.

For example:

```
$parentWidth = $('#stickThis').closest('.tableBox').innerWidth();
$('#stickThis').width($parentWidth);
```

Full code:

```
function sticktothetop() {
    var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var top = $('#stick-here').offset().top;
    if (window_top > top) {
        $('#stickThis').addClass('stick');
        setWidth();
        $('#stick-here').height($('#stickThis').outerHeight());
    } else {
        $('#stickThis').width('auto');
        $('#stickThis').removeClass('stick');
        $('#stick-here').height(0);
    }
}

$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(sticktothetop);
    sticktothetop();
});

function setWidth() {
    if ($('#stickThis').hasClass('stick')) {
        $parentWidth = $('#stickThis').closest('.tableBox').innerWidth();
        $('#stickThis').width($parentWidth);
    }
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    setWidth();
});
```

Also you should call the `setWidth` function on window resize to fix the width of the element.

Comment: Tested in your example https://jsbin.com/fobiyajunu/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

You can change the following css rule:

```
#stickThis.stick {
    position: sticky; /* instead of fixed*/
}
```